# What are the best loss functions to try for very noisy data in a regression model?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multiple-regression

I have very noisy data and I would like to build linear regression model to predict the output and afterward interperate the model. Currently I'm using Lasso regression, where uses square loss function. I was wondering what would be the best loss function for noisy setting? Is there any rule of thumbs that I can choose among them ?

Answer (score -1):

It is not the loss function that matters, but the type of regularization and the constant that multiplies the regularization term is important. If your data is very noisy, it is usually better to choose a bigger multiplier.
Anyway, I recommend you to first preprocess your data and then apply regression.

Comment: I don't think so.